# Find elements containing specific value within custom tag with space-separated values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-selectors

Imagine I have something like this:

```
<li tags="1 3 "></li>
<li tags="2 3 "></li>
<li tags="4 "></li>
```

Tags are separated by space. What in my head is to find `<li>`s by tags that are put in as custom attribute in order not to make another query just to find projects with the tag selected.

Is there anyway to for example to find all `<li>`s with the tag `3` and the result to be something like this :

`result = <li tags ="1 3 "></li><li tags ="2 3 "></li>`

so I can put it in the container like `$('.container').html(result);`

Or maybe a better way: find the `<li>`s that does not have that tag and add css property of `display: none`

I think the latter is more efficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use `~=`: to find `li` elements, that have '3' in `tags` attribute value:

```
$('li[tags~=3]');
```

And use `:not()` selector to find elements, that don't have '3', and hide them:

```
 $('li:not([tags~=3])').hide();
```

If you want to target `li` with specific class, use `li.class`.

Comment: is there anything like `li[tags!~=3]` ?

Comment: I think I found my answer will come back to you

Comment: Awesome It works like a charm, is the anyway to add a class as well? I mean if I want to separate my li's with a class like project. I want it to work only on them.

Comment: `$('li.project:not([tags~=3])').hide();` will this work?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function ()
        {
            var a = $("[tags*='3']");

        });
```

it will result you li that contains 3 in tags attribute.alternative is var `a=$("li[tags*='3']")`

Comment: This will also match 13, 23, 31 and so on.